# ios UIScrollView - buttons exceed boundries

Tags: uiscrollview

I'm adding buttons to my scrollview via code but when I run the app, I see all the buttons and they exceed the scrollview boundries instead of only some.

In the attached screenshot, you can see that the scrollbar is inside the boundries of the scrollview, only the buttons exceed.

why do I need self.recentFriendsScrollView.delegate = self;??

Here is my code:
//recentOpponents is an array

```
NSInteger xOffset = 0;
CGFloat size = 38;
CGFloat padding = 5;

self.recentFriendsScrollView.delegate = self;
for (User *user in recentOpponents) {
    UIButton *tagButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    tagButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    tagButton.frame = CGRectMake(xOffset, 8, size, size);
    [self.recentFriendsScrollView addSubview:tagButton];

    xOffset += size;
    xOffset += padding;
}
[self.recentFriendsScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(xOffset, 50.0f)];
```

[image](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/855/screenshot20130223at820.png/)

Thanks
D

Answer (score 0):

Your scrollview frame is not proper.
If you have set it programmatically, show the rect of frame. If it is set via sib, check your resizing flags again.